# Can I efficiently construct a Voronoi diagram / Delaunay mesh from a subset of points?

Tags: algorithm, graph, voronoi, delaunay

I have a problem where I have a large number (~10,000) points (in 2-D) from which I need to repeatedly pick a small number (~100) and construct a Voronoi diagram.

I can pre-compute the Voronoi diagram / Delaunay mesh for the 10000 points which always remain the same. Is there then a way to efficiently compute the Voronoi diagram for a small subset of these points? Or do I need to start from scratch every time?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm going to say that you need to start from scratch. For a simple example, start with 3 points and draw the Voronoi diagram. Then remove one point and observe the changes. Then imagine doing that when you remove 99% of the points. There's going to be no useful relationship between the diagram with 10000 points and the diagram with 100 points.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you see the term "dynamic algorithms" used to describe the process of taking an algorithm where the input is typically always known up front and modify it to handle the case where the underlying data change. In your case, you're looking for "dynamic Voronoi diagrams," which are data structures that maintain Voronoi diagrams even as nodes are added and deleted.

I am not particularly familiar with dynamic computational geometry algorithms, but a bit of Googling turned up a couple of hits for "dynamic Voronoi diagrams," including [this paper by Gowda, Kirkpatrick, et al](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1056738) describing one approach. It may not end up being faster in your case than just computing the full Voronoi diagram, but it could be useful as a starting point for a search.

Comment: Your idea is to precompute the diagram for 10000 points and then dynamically remove 9900 of them? That really doesn’t sound like an efficiency win.

Comment: @Sneftel I agree that this wouldn’t be efficient. My answer was mostly geared toward introducing the relevant term to search for in the hope that someone somewhere had solved this particular special case. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For such a small input set (100 vertices) just building a Delauany mesh/Voronoi diagram from scratch should be reasonably fast.  While I don't pretend to have an exhaustive knowledge of the algorithms that exist today, my experience with the Delaunay is that the logic for removing vertices from a mesh tends to be more expensive than adding to the mesh.  So the approach of creating a mesh of 100 points from a mesh of 10000 by removing vertices probably would not succeed.

Here's a sample of Java code using the  [Tinfour](https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour) library.  Building 1000 Voronoi diagrams required only 277 milliseconds on a middle-of-the-road laptop computer.   The focus of the Tinfour library is the Delaunay rather than the Voronoi, but it does include a so-so class for building a Voronoi from a Delaunay mesh. I think that any good computational geometry library you find should yield similar performance.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int seed = 0;
    List<Vertex> masterList = TestVertices.makeRandomVertices(10000, seed);
    int nTrials = 1000;
    int nVerticesInSubset = 100;
    int nPolygons = 0;
    Random random = new Random(seed);
    long time0 = System.nanoTime();
    for (int iTrial = 0; iTrial < nTrials; iTrial++) {
        // we wish to build a subset of N unique vertices.
        // the bitSet allows us to avoid randomly selecting
        // a vertex more than once.
        BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(10000);
        ArrayList<Vertex> subList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nVerticesInSubset; i++) {
            while (true) {
                int index = random.nextInt(masterList.size());
                // the random index is a value in the range 0 to 10000.
                // see if the corresponding vertex has already been selected
                // if not, add it to the subList.  if so, keep looking
                if (!bitSet.get(index)) {
                    subList.add(masterList.get(index));
                    bitSet.set(index);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        IncrementalTin tin = new IncrementalTin(0.001);
        tin.add(subList, null);
        BoundedVoronoiDiagram voronoi = new BoundedVoronoiDiagram(tin);
        nPolygons += voronoi.getPolygons().size();
    }
    long time1 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Elapsed time in milliseconds " + (time1 - time0) / 1.0e+6);
    System.out.println("Avg. polygons in Voronoi " + ((double) nPolygons / nTrials));
}
```